# Visual indicators for local Git repositories

Tags: git, osx-mountain-lion

When I was using Turtoise SVN I could see visual indicator like a green check mark, blue plus button, etc... on the folders and files that I had checked out from a SVN repo but with Git I get nothing! It looks like a normal file and folder and it is hard to visually know that it is a Git repo and not a local folder, etc...
Is there any cool tool for Git that helps with that?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can just use [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/). Id adds the indicators you are looking for:

[image: Visual Indicators]

Comment: This answer is unfortunately not relevant as the question is precisely for MacOS.

Comment: yes correct, I am looking for Mac,  sorry for confusion in question.